# Closing the Window from Visual Web Part Page in Chrome is not working

Tags: javascript, visual-web-part, chrome

```
<script  lang="Javascript">
    function quitBox(cmd) {
        if (cmd == 'quit') {
            open(location, '_self').close();
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
<input type="button" name="Quit" id="Quit" value="Quit" onclick="return quitBox('quit');" />
```

I have the above code in a Visual Web part. I would like to close the window upon clicking the button. This code is working fine in IE but not in Chrome. How do I close a window with Chrome which is in a Visual Web Part?

Answer (score 1):

You can't anymore because Chrome has become more tight on security a couple of months ago (self-redirection exploit)

and won't let a script close the window.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome

Has all the details

Comment: I am using the above mentioned script from the URL that you have mentioned unfortunately, it is working in Standard Web page but not in a Visual Web part page.